# Flask Jinja2 fetch row <audio src="LINK" /> not working

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-mysql

I add file as <audio src="LINK" controls /> to mysql.
When I fetch mysql row it not show audio player but show text <audio src="LINK" controls /> instead of embeded audio player